# python How can I stop an infinite while loop and continue with rest of code?

Tags: python, while-loop, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

The problem is that I can not exit the while loop without stopping the entire program.

When I execute the code on my Raspberry Pi, the camera starts recording, but when I want to end the video and press Ctrl+c, the entire program stops instead of continuing after the while loop. I thought the signal handler would catch the keyboard interrupt but it does not.

My code:

```
import picamera
import signal
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        global interrupted
        interrupted = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

interrupted = False

# Setup the camera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1640, 922)
    camera.framerate = 30

    # Start recording
    camera.start_recording("pythonVideo.h264")

while True:
        sleep(0.5)
        print("still recording")

        if interrupted:
                print("Ctrl+C pressed")
                camera.stop_recording()
                break

# Stop recording
#camera.stop_recording()

# The camera is now closed.

print("We are going to convert the video.")
# Define the command we want to execute.
command = "MP4Box -add pythonVideo.h264 convertedVideo.mp4 -fps 30"
#Execute command.
call([command], shell=True)
# Video converted.
print("Video converted.")
```

What I tried:

```
bflag = True
while bflag ==True:
        sleep(0.5)
        print("still recording")

        if interrupted:
                print("Ctrl+C pressed")
                camera.stop_recording()
                bflag = False
```

Error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/useThisFolder $ python cookieVideo.py 
still recording
still recording
still recording
still recording
still recording
^Cstill recording
Ctrl+C pressed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cookieVideo.py", line 29, in <module>
    camera.stop_recording()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1193, in stop_recording
'port %d' % splitter_port)
picamera.exc.PiCameraNotRecording: There is no recording in progress on port 1
```

Comment: replace the "while True" with while somevar, and change this variable to False when you want to exit the loop

Comment: There is no need for things like "Disclaimer: Absolute noob attempting to explain a question.". The onus of asking a proper question is on you regardless of status, and trust me when I say noobishness will show if it's there. No need to apologize for it, just take the time to listen and learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do it:

```
while True:
    try:
        sleep(0.5)
        print("still recording")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ctrl+C pressed")
        camera.stop_recording()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I implement your solution, ctrl+c does nothing. The while loop keeps going.

Comment: You need this code *instead*  of the signal handler stuff.

Comment: If I use this code instead, I get the error mentioned in the problem description.

Comment: Ah, this needs to be **within** the `with picamera.PiCamera() as camera` block. I suspect recording stops automatically when you leave that block.

Comment: It is fixed. It was an indentation problem. I needed to use 4 spaces instead of tabs, because I am modifying the code using nano (I think that is the reason, don't know for sure). Thank you.

Comment: A common problem! In a terminal, many will recommend vi or emacs for coding, and of course there are many IDEs that will help you avoid such problems.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

As you can see it works perfectly with @mdurant's code.

Comment: When I try this it gives an error, which I added to the question description.

Comment: The code provided by @mdurant works perfectly for me, try it again and see that your indentation is correct.